# Is there any fundamental difference between using @inject vs. [Inject] dependency injection with Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

Say I have this:

**SomePage.razor:**

```
@inject Something something
@page "/somepage"

<h1> My Page </h1>

@code {
    // Using "Something" here ...
}
```

Is there any fundamental difference to this:

**AnotherPage.razor:**

```
@page "/anotherpage"

<h1> My Page </h1>

@code {
    [Inject]
    Something something { get; set; }
    // Using "Something" here ...
}
```

Or will they both work identically, and this is just "programmer preference"?

Answer (score 6):

the two approaches are identical. In fact the @inject syntax is simply shorthand for the [Inject] syntax

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Blazor and tried both approaches, but nothing seemed to change, so I was wondering if there was [probably] some reason to use one over the other. That an "expert" would know.

Comment: Tried to find documentation that describes this claim, but failed to do so, do you happen to know where this is documented?

Comment: @RandRandom https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#request-a-service-in-a-component

Comment: Here is the English version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#request-a-service-in-a-component

Answer (score 2):

An Addendum to elaborate on @Yasseros answer:

This is a demo Razor file - *Pages/Inject.razor*:

```
@page "/inject"
@namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject NavigationManager NavManager1
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@code {
    [Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager2 { get; set; }
    [InjectAttribute] private NavigationManager NavManager3 { get; set; }
}
```

Which gets pre-compiled to the following C# file -  viewable in the obj folder structure at *obj/debug/net5.0/Razor/Pages/Inject.razor.g.cs*:

```cs
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/inject")]
    public partial class Inject : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
        }

    [Inject] private NavigationManager NavManager2 { get; set; }

    [InjectAttribute] private NavigationManager NavManager3 { get; set; }
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.InjectAttribute] private NavigationManager NavManager1 { get; set; }
    }
```

`@inject` is Razor attribute markup syntax that gets translated into C# Attribute syntax.  The same applies to `@page` translating into `RouteAttribute` syntax on the class.